# rename command doesn't rename

Tags: perl, shell

This should work on my CentOS 6.6 but somehow the file name is not changed. What am I missing here?

```
rename -f  's/silly//'  sillytest.zi
```

This should rename `sillytest.zi` to `test.zi` but the name is not changed. Of course I can use `mv` command but I want to apply to many files and patterns.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which version of `rename` have you got? Are you sure there aren't any whitespace characters in the filename? What does `rename -n -v 's/silly//' *` say?

Comment: rename (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)

Comment: Ah, the old switcharoo. There are two programs called `rename`, and I have a different one from yours.

Comment: rename -n -v 's/silly//' *  executed, no error, silent, but name not changed

Comment: Why is this question tagged perl?

Comment: @MattJacob Probably because rename is written in Perl and uses Perl syntax for its arguments. See [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL) at metacpan.org.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Perl's rename solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different `rename` utilities commonly used on GNU/Linux systems.

## util-linux version

On Red Hat-based systems (such as CentOS), `rename` is a compiled executable provided by the `util-linux` package. It’s a simple program with very simple usage (from the relevant man page):

```
rename from to file...
```

> `rename` will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of `from` in their name by `to`.

Newer versions also support a useful `-v, --verbose` option.

**NB:** If a file already exists whose name coincides with the new name of the file being renamed, then this `rename` command will silently (without warning) over-write the pre-existing file.

#### Example

Fix the extension of HTML files so that all `.htm` files have a four-letter `.html` suffix:

```
rename .htm .html *.htm
```

#### Example from question

To rename `sillytest.zi` to `test.zi`, replace `silly` with an empty string:

```
rename silly '' sillytest.zi
```

## Perl version

On Debian-based systems ,`rename` is a Perl script which is much more capable
as you get the benefit of Perl’s rich set of regular expressions.

Its usage is (from its man page):

```
rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]
```

> `rename` renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the first argument.

This `rename` command also includes a `-v, --verbose` option. Equally useful is its `-n, --no-act` which can be used as a dry-run to see which files would be renamed. Also, it won’t over-write pre-existing files unless the `-f, --force` option is used.

#### Example

Fix the extension of HTML files:

```
rename s/\.htm$/.html/ *.htm
```