# rename files containing _2_ to -2- returns invalid option -- '2'

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to rename all files containing `_2_` to `-2-`

```
find ./ -depth -name "*_2_*" -exec /usr/bin/rename  _2_ '-2-' {} \+
```

but I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/rename: invalid option -- '2'
```

Comment: I presume you're using a Red-Hat based distribution of GNU/Linux but it would be best to clarify this as there are [two different `rename` commands](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35351757/1640661).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem when dealing with filenames that have a leading `-`, because this is the same character used to indicate command line options.

A fairly common behavior is to interpret the argument `--` to mean "end of options", so you can do something like:

```
find ./ -depth -name "*_2_*" -exec /usr/bin/rename -- _2_ '-2-' {} \+
```

I've tested this locally and that seems to Do The Right Thing on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Or.. you could simply add \ before the - to tell the command that it is a symboll. So for example:

```
sudo rename "1x." "\-1x." *.*
```

That would work and won't give you an error.